# select slow because of unused inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, innodb

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
CREATE TABLE `B` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `c_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IX_a_id` (`a_id`),
  KEY `IX_c_id` (`c_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `a_id_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `A` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

They have a couple million rows each.

```
explain select count(*) FROM B inner join A on B.a_id = A.id WHERE B.c_id = 7;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys         | key        | key_len | ref                | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | B     | ref    | IX_a_id,IX_c_id       | IX_c_id    | 4       | const              | 116624 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY    | 4       | test1.B.a_id       |      1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+--------+-------------+
```

Now, I can't understand why mysql is unable to ignore the un-needed inner join to A which kills performance. i.e., the following query is equivalent to the above:

```
select count(*) from B where B.c_id = 7
```

which should be easy to infer since B.a_id can't be null and B.a_id has a constraint to the unique key A.id

Is there a way to make mysql understand this ?

Comment: did you try to specify what columns you want to count instead of *?
something like: SELECT count(B.C_id) from B where B.c_id =7

Comment: Good point Steffo, however this only makes a difference if there are large numbers of columns being returned. In this can, select *  will return 4 vs your select B.c_id which returns 1. As the count(*) counts rows anyhow, this would be unlikely to make much difference over 4 vs 1 columns in the join.

Comment: count(B.a_id) does not make any difference vs count(*)

Comment: There is a way to make MySQL understand. Omit the JOIN you don't need. You told it to join something, it did, now you expect that a computer is able to guess what the programmer meant. Seriously? Also, what kills performance is 120% insufficient innodb_buffer_pool_size, but better bark at the wrong tree than getting to the core issue, right?

Comment: That indexed join should barely impact your performance.  As for whether the join is unnecessary or not, a `left join` would be, but by making it an `inner join` you are implicitly saying you only want to match the rows that also match in the second table. Or in other words, by putting the `inner join` there, you are MAKING it needed. Your two queries are not equivalent

Answer (score 0):

SQL statements that include a join will scan both tables and load them into temporary storage ahead of doing the join. This means it loads both the tables into a temporary table, sorts and removes the unnecessary duplicates and returns the results. You can speed this up by using sub-queries as the tables to join.

For example if you did the following, you would are unlikely to get your performance penalty:

```
select count(*) FROM 
(select * from B where B.c_id = 7 and B.a_id is not Null) as sub_b
inner join 
(select * from A where A.id is not Null) as sub_a
on (sub_b.a_id = sub_a.id);
```

This is because SQL is behaving as you would expect and pre-filtering the results to join thus loading less into it's temporary table. You can speed this up further using indexes on the id on A, and the c_id and a_id on B

If you have a large number of columns, reducing the number of columns returned in the queries will also speed it up:

```
select count(sub_b.a_id) FROM 
(select a_id from B where B.c_id = 7 and B.a_id is not Null) as sub_b
inner join 
(select id from A where A.id is not Null) as sub_a
on (sub_b.a_id = sub_a.id);
```

----edit----

a good point was made below, the second select is unnecessary. The first sub-select ensures that the where clause we care about is applied first.

Try this:

```
select count(sub_b.a_id) FROM 
(select a_id from B where B.c_id = 7) as sub_b
inner join A on (sub_b.a_id = A.id);
```

Comment: 1) the merge join algorithm you describe to implement the join is sometimes used but not always. 2) I can't see how the above would make any difference. i.e., the "is not null" statements you have added make no sense since the relevant columns are defined as NOT NULL. I can't see how blindly selecting all rows from A will help mysql figure out that the join is un-needed. (I did try the above and I can confirm that it is actually worse in terms of performance)

Comment: Good point on the nulls, I have updated. The purpose on the sub-select is to only bring into the join the records you care about. SQL should then respond in the way you expect by ditching the join to A. Indexes on B.c_id, B.a_id and A.id should improve it's performance

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I can't understand why mysql is unable to ignore the un-needed inner join to A which kills performance.

Addressing that implied question...

File a bug report to suggest such an optimization.  http://bugs.mysql.com .